# How can I move bones in the Weight Painting section ? (DEF Bones)

Tags: rigging

I'm having trouble controlling the weight painting of the generated rig. Is it possible to move bones and paint weights at the same time ?

[image: Spine Bones Can't Move]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tend to keyframe parts of a rig going through some extreme ranges of motion.
Then you just scrub the timeline while editing weights.  Does that sound like it would help?

Comment: Can you also tell me how to do this ? I'm not entirely familiar with Blender.

Comment: Ha!  I, too, am a newcomer to Blender.  I can give you the right breadcrumb trail of terms to look up, though I'll leave it to the veterans for a deep dive.

Comment: Basically, the  bone systems (joints if you're a maya alum) are "Armatures".
Armatures are the "Object" level and can be edited spatially in "Edit" mode but you'll be doing the animating in "Pose" mode.  When you are in Pose mode, you can set keyframes on the PRS of individual joints or control shapes that the rig might possess. (Different rigs might handle it differently).   I hope that's not too confusing and gives you  a little bit of a springboard to learn about the Blender way.  Happy Blending!